# Table with select/deselect and summarize option

Tags: javascript, html, addition, calculator

I've created a table. Now I'm trying to have an `onClick` event add an option where I can click the squares inside the table to select them and click again to deselect them. At the end I wish to have it to display the total amount, by that I mean that it adds together the selected squars like a calculator would do.

```
<style>
    table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
</style>

<table>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="b8cce4">Modell</td>
    <td>Trend</td>
    <td>Titanum</td>
    <td>Familiepakke</td>
    <td>Førerassistentpakke</td>
    <td>Stilpakke</td>
    <td>Final price</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="b8cce4"><b>Kuga</b></td>
    <td>401000</td>
    <td>420000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>10200</td>
    <td>9200</td>
    <td>$</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="b8cce4"><b>C-max</b></td>
    <td>320000</td>
    <td>335000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>9400</td>
    <td>3600</td>
    <td>$</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="b8cce4"><b>Focus</b></td>
    <td>255000</td>
    <td>325000</td>
    <td>900</td>
    <td>12500</td>
    <td>9000</td>
    <td>$</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="b8cce4"><b>Mondeo</b></td>
    <td>281000</td>
    <td>361000</td>
    <td>1100</td>
    <td>9900</td>
    <td>7200</td>
    <td>$</td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to make it so that I can click on one of the slots, able to select multiple, and at the end it will display the total price for all selected options.

Comment: add an attribute which holds the current state like `<td clicked="true">`

Comment: I try to have it so when the square is clicked, it changes the background so it looks like it is toggled, having the option to be de-toggled changing the background back to white

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you add/remove a class to your TD's. The "selected" can then have a different background color.

If you're using jQuery, you can use something like this (not tested):

```
$('td').click(function() { 
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Now you can use the CSS class to indicate it is selected.

I've added a JSFiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/vhwLxhsg/

I hope this is what you are looking for :-)

UPDATE:
Added calc. for each row, as requested: https://jsfiddle.net/vhwLxhsg/2/

UPDATE 2: 
Vanilla JS version: https://jsfiddle.net/vhwLxhsg/4/

Comment: Thank you so much, but I noticed a bug with it, when you click one of the squares under the "Final Price" tag, it breakes, and do you know how to display the price inside the finalprice slot for each single row?

Comment: Very likely, it was thrown together. I didn't validate anything, so e.g. the $ will cause NaN :) But I think you get the point.

Comment: Let me just have a look at it - one moment :-)

Comment: Cant say it enough, thank you so much! You got no idea how happy this actually makes me, been struggeling with this for the last 8 hours without any trace of success, thank you again!

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but im a little bit new to JS, and im sorta struggeling to impliment this in my own file, or notepad++ document, do you mind doing me this last favor and teach me how to do it to correctly work with the different parts?

Comment: Sure thing. What do you need me to explain/help you with specifically?

Comment: Im not too familiar of jQuary, so there it multiple question regarding it. How can I add it to the others, how do i link it. Different question, is it possible to have this table do the current command by using java instead? Thanks either way.

Comment: To use jQuery, go to: https://jquery.com/ and download jQuery (button to the right). Next you download the jquery.js-file. Place it next to your HTML file (or anywhere, as long as you know how to write the path to it). Add this, inside your <head> tag: <head>
...
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
...
</head>

Now jQuery is available in your code. Be sure your own script is included AFTER jQuery, otherwise jQuery will be undefined. If you by Java, mean actual Java, then Yes, you can. But it will require a post-back for each click. You can however write the same code without jQuery.

Comment: Using regular / vanilla JavaScript. It just takes a few more lines of code, as jQuery handles some of the loops for us. Like we've only attached "click" once, instead of doing it in a loop for each TD etc.

Comment: I see. I understand if this might sound a bit exhausting, but is there any chance you can make a java version of this? At the moment I use my school computer to code, as thats the one I currently have avaliable, but it is unable to download items from the internet. So sadly I cannot download jquery. I understand if you choose to pass on this one, and you have already been a ton of help. But you would be a lifesaver if you  could make a java version

Comment: I have never written a single line of Java, but I can give you a vanilla JavaScript version instead. So you don't need jQuery.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vhwLxhsg/4/ for vanilla JS. Only works in IE10+ in this condition :-)

Comment: It seems that the external file linked to the jsfiddle is in jQuery. Anyways, thank you for the help, but sadly I really need it in JS. I am trying to learn JS and trying to understand jQuery will most likely achieve me little as I want to be able to explain what the actual code does if one were to ask.

Comment: Did you see the updated answer? It's written in pure JS, without jQuery. :-) Look at update 2.

Comment: Its a big chance that I just lack experiense with coding, but do I still need to download the jQuery file to connect all of it?

Comment: Nope, not if you use the latest version of the jsfiddle. It should be pure JavaScript - no need for jQuery references.

Comment: Oh, I ment as if I were to run the program on my own computer, trying to host it locally through my browser.

Comment: Yes, it should work just fine. You need to copy the code from JSFiddle into a local HTML file and save it to your computer - but there are no external references or the like needed. :)

Comment: Sadly, I cannot seem to get it working on my pc. saved it as jsquery.js, linked my html document to it, but it just do not want to cooperate.

Comment: You can copy/paste the HTML field of this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vhwLxhsg/6/ (I have moved everything into the HTML area, so you can open a notepad -> paste the HTML field code -> save as HTML). It should work fine, unless you're on an older browser?

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you'll become the next JavaScript ninja/guru! Good luck with everything!